# Why do I have to turn off cascade delete here in Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I've got two models here:

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name"), Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Assessment> SentAssessment { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Assessment> ReceivedAssessment { get; set; }
}

public class Assessment
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Student Source { get; set; }

    public Student Target { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Assessment Content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Assessment>()
        .HasRequired(eval => eval.Source)
        .WithMany(stu => stu.SentAssessment)
        .Map(conf => conf.MapKey("SourceId"))
        .WillCascadeOnDelete();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Assessment>()
        .HasRequired(eval => eval.Target)
        .WithMany(stu => stu.ReceivedAssessment)
        .Map(conf => conf.MapKey("TargetId"))
        .WillCascadeOnDelete();
}
```

In this design the users (students) can give assessment to others. He or she can  see both the assessments he / she has given to others and received from others.

While deleting a student, all of his / hers sent or received assessments should be deleted. So I wrote the WillCascadeOnDelete statement but I get an error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Evaluations_dbo.Students_TargetId' on table 'Evaluations' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Where are the "cycles or multiple cascade paths" here?

Comment: How about `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();` below `base.OnModelCreating...`

Answer (score 0):

This is because when cascade delete occurs in `Student` database doesnt know in which order it should delete `Assessment`. You have to manually tell database how to do it:

```
create trigger T_Student_D
on Student
instead of delete
as
    set nocount on
    delete from Assessment
    where TargetId in (select ID from deleted) or
    SourceId in (select ID from deleted)

    delete from Student where ID in (select ID from deleted)
```

It is common problem with multiple foreign key which refers to the same entity.